# Is there a way to select a Table without a direct reference to its name?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a macro that loops through all the sheets in the workbook and updates the tables on them. All sheets are copies of the same template, so as new sheets are created, the table name just goes up by one (Table3, Table4, Table5...) I am not sure how to set it up in the `For` loop to go through each row of the table without a direct reference

```
For Each Sheet in Workbook
    Set tbl = ActiveSheets.ListObjects
    For i = 13 To tbl.ListRows.Count
        ' Code to refresh
```

Not sure what to put after the `ListObjects` so that it goes to the table. This currently gives an error stating *Run-Time Error '424' Object Required*

Comment: `ListObjects` is a collection, just loop over it. For Each tbl in Sheet1.ListObjects....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `Option Explicit` (see tools/options, and check the "require variable declaration" box) and using undeclared variables. You'd be asking about a *type mismatch* error on this line if `tbl` was a declared `ListObject`:

> ```
> Set tbl = ActiveSheets.ListObjects
> ```

..and you wouldn't have had an "object required" error, because the compiler would have then told you that `ActiveSheets` doesn't exist. This error is raised because `ActiveSheets` is a `Variant/Empty` that doesn't contain or refer to anything: it's just an empty, undeclared variable, but a `.ListObjects` member call would *require* it to be an object with a valid reference - hence, "object required".

You want `ActiveSheet` probably, but more likely you want *one specific sheet*. In any case, you don't want to make member calls against it, because `ActiveSheet` is a `Variant/Object`, which means any member calls made against are late-bound and can only be resolved at run-time: you want to let the compiler do its job here, and tell you when something is wrong, *before* the code gets to run.

`ListRows` is a property that yields an object collection (just like `ListObjects`), containing `ListRow` objects: you DON'T want to use a `For` loop to iterate those. Object collections are best iterated with a `For Each` loop:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet '<~ todo: change to the specific sheet you want to work with

Dim table As ListObject
For Each table In sheet.ListObjects
    Dim currentRow As ListRow
    For Each currentRow In table.ListRows
        '...
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Think that will work. I am getting a new error that won't let me run it quite yet... I have a ```For Each Sheet In Workbook``` Loop, but its giving me a *Compile Error: invalid Next Control Variable reference* on my ```Next Sheet``` to close the loop, Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @Liworker just make it `Next` and drop the (optional/redundant) identifier there. The compile error is because you've either left out the inner `Next` (there should be two), or there's a mismatch and you have e.g. `For Each thing1` and then `Next thing2` is closing that loop - that won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
Dim sheet, tbl, obj
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets  ' or    ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set tbl = sheet.ListObjects
    For i = 13 To tbl.Count
    'or
    For Each obj In tbl
```